# Optimize this insert SQL Query

Tags: sql, performance, sqlite, select, insert

I've been trying to find out why my SQLite database is performing relatively slowly (4 seconds to insert 1500 records) and I think I've narrowed it down to this query. Is there a way to optimise this?

```
 "INSERT OR REPLACE INTO MainFrame(WID,PName,PAlias,PModel,FriendID, UniverseID, GalaxyID) VALUES
  ((SELECT WID FROM Worlds WHERE WName= ?),
  @pname,
  @palias,
  @pmodel,
  (SELECT FriendID FROM Friend WHERE FriendName = @eFriend),
  (SELECT UniverseID FROM Universes WHERE UniverseName = @eUniverse),
  (SELECT GalaxyID FROM Galaxies WHERE GalaxyName = @eGalaxy ))";
```

As you can see, there are a few `Selects` being used in an insert query. The reason for this is because the loop inserts data into other tables (`WID`, `FriendID`, `UniverseID`, `GalaxyID`) so I don't have that data until it's been inserted. I need this data to insert into the `MainFrame` table but this feels like a brute force approach. Any advice?

Comment: Have you narrowed it down to which part of the query is the problem? ie have you run the select on its own to see how quickly it returns. If the select is slow, maybe look at indexes. If select is quick maybe its indexes on the MainFrame table that's slowing insertion.

Comment: @DavidOsborne - I ran a few more tests, but it seems that even after the indexes were removed from the MainFrame, it still took 4 or more seconds. Individual select statements are fast enough.

Comment: @DavidOsborne - I indexed the column `WName` from the firt value and now it's sped up to 500ms. I'm worried about space issues, but should suffice for now. You can post that as the answer if you like as it was the suggested of checking if the select was slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you narrowed it down to which part of the query is the problem? ie have you run the select on its own to see how quickly it returns. If the select is slow, maybe look at indexes. If select is quick maybe its indexes on the MainFrame table that's slowing insertion.

Answer (score 0):

If your ID fields are autoincrementing, you can get their value right after inserting the respective record by calling [`sqlite3_last_insert_rowid()`](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/last_insert_rowid.html) in the C API, or the corresponding function in your language.

(Also use one transaction for all inserts.)

Comment: They are autoincrementing but they use an `insert of ignore` command so there are no duplicated. This throws off the `sqlite3_last_insert_rowid()` value.